# How do i maintain the state of a UI element in detail and listing page using RxJava android

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

Let say the favorite button is pressed on detail page then on back press when I come back on listing page I wanted the state of the button to be shown as the view of pressed, using RxJava

Comment: What are the reasons for doing this with RxJava?

Comment: in theory u can put a observable on the button , and subscribe it where u want to . show up your code, would be able to help better then

Comment: You need to maintain Individual List of Status or a variable of each with item for the same and update ui on the call